# Eyebrow not moving with head

Tags: rigging

I made a simple character , rigged it . But the problem is that when i move the head in object mode . Eyebrow moves along with it . But when i do the same when using pose mode ( using bone to move head ) everything part of head moves EXCEPT eyebrows . Can anyone plz help me with it ??

https://www.dropbox.com/s/j8vkahgn2lrco0v/error%20mouth.blend?dl=0

( link to the .blend file )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Go in Pose mode, click on the head bone, and find out its name.
2. Go to Edit mode (on the mesh) and select the eyelashes.
3. select the vertex group with the same name as the head bone in the properties tab, and click on assign.

   [image]

Comment: Thnx alot sir , love this community . Where people are so helpful .